# Calling VBA custom Function in the main Subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I have two functions that both determine the output depending on the value in a cell. The outcome is Column N should have a combined output of function mBlineCTG + findShpc. They separately work, I would like to call them on the main function that way I don't have to run both routines separately. Am open to help including the logic behind

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Main()
 M_xx
 f_xxx
 Cells(i, 14).Value = M_xx + f_xxx
 Range("Q1").Value = "xxx_xxxx"
End Sub

Public Function M_xxx()
 Dim LastRow As Long
 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim  s_Cxx
 Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To LastRow
Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 10).Value, 1))
    Case "s"
        s_Cxx = "D"
    Case "0"
         s_Cxx= "SD"
    Case "1", "R", "E", "F"
        Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 13).Value, 2))
          Case "13"
             s_Cxx = "SB"
            Case Else
             s_Cxx = "SS"
        End Select
    Case "I"
      s_Cxx = "IS"
    Case "2", "15"
         s_Cxx = "BB"
    Case "3"
         s_Cxx = "SF"
    Case Else
         s_Cxx = ""
 End Select

    Next i
End Function

Public Function f_xxxx()
 'declare variables
 Dim LastRow As Long

 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 'Dim ThisCont
 'ThisCont = Range("E2").Value
  Dim S_xxx2
  'loop thru' rows 
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 2 To LastRow
  Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 5).Value, 1))
   'Select Case ThisCont
        Case "A"
           S_xxx2 = "big-base-Post-01 0 01 Cee-xx-04"
        Case "X"
           S_xxx2 = "small-shelf-Post-01 0 01 Cee-xx-01"
        Case Else
           S_xxx2= "big-drawer-Post-01 0 01 Cee-xx-06"
  End Select
   'Cells(i, 14).Value = S_xxx2
 Next i
End Function
```

Comment: it looks like you are calling both of them from the main function. It's not really clear what you are after.

Comment: Yes, you're calling both functions twice. Can you elaborate on what is the output you're getting, and how that differs from what you expect?

Comment: The Range "N1" value is just the column header, the results are supposed to populate from N2 to FinalRow. The output I want fill this is if for example if Cell E1 value is "C"  then function findShpc returns this string "S-Sh-PS-01 0 01 CC-SM-01 and function mBlinCTG returns a "V"

Comment: Sorry pressed  enter before finishing, So Column "N2" onward should populate with both the returns of functions. At the moment, If I run the functions as subs they output the desired results but I cant them to run as functions in the main sub. I get error 1004  "Application defined or object- defined  error"

Comment: David,  thanks for your response, I tried your solution but got the same error.

Comment: @joes I made a small revision to begin writing the data in `"N2"` cell. Can you tell me what line raises the error? Because it does not cause any errors when I test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some confusion, as you're calling both functions twice.

The first call to each is redundant as it does not *return* any value to the main procedure. The second call is an error since `i` is undefined in the scope of `Main` procedure.

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Main()
 mBlineCTG   '<-- calls the mBlineCTG function but does not return any value
 findShpc    '<-- calls the findShpc function but does not return any value
 Cells(i, 14).Value = mBlineCTG + findShpc  'This line is an error because "i" _
                                             is undefined, but this would writes the _
                                             sum of two functions to Column N/Row i, _
                                             if "i" is an integer >= 1
 Range("N1").Value = "SHP_SRC"  '<-- overwrites the value in Range("N1")
End Sub
```

I think this is what you need:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Main()
 Range("N1").Value = mBlineCTG & findShpc  '<-- concatenates mBlineCTG and findShpc in to range("N1")
End Sub
```

Also, I note that neither of your functions has a return value of any sort, so this actually won't write anything in to the N1 cell... You're going to need to elaborate more on what is the expected output.

I think this might take care of it, do the loop in the main function (instead of redundant loop in the called functions):

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim i As Long

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To FinalRow
    Range("N2").Cells(i).Value = mBlineCTG(i) & findShpc(i) '<-- concatenates mBlineCTG and findShpc in to range("N1")
Next
End Sub


Public Function mBlineCTG(i As Long)
    Dim ThisCont
    Dim shpCt As String

    Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 13).Value, 1))
        Case "D"
            shpCt = "D"
        Case "0"
            shpCt = "V"
        Case "1", "R", "E", "F"
            Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 13).Value, 2))
              Case "13"
                shpCt = "B"
                Case Else
                shpCt = "S"
            End Select
        Case "I"
            shpCt = "I"
        Case "2", "15"
            shpCt = "B"
        Case "3"
            shpCt = "F"
        Case Else
            shpCt = ""
     End Select

     '#### RETURN THE VALUE TO CALLING PROCEDURE:
     mBlineCTG = shpCt

End Function

Public Function findShpc(i As Long)
  Dim SHPcT2 As String
  Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 5).Value, 1))
   'Select Case ThisCont
        Case "A"
           SHPcT2 = "L-BM-PS-01 0 01 CC-LG-01"
        Case "X"
           SHPcT2 = "X-BM-PS-01 0 01 CC-XX-01"
        Case Else
           SHPcT2 = "S-SH-PS-01 0 01 CC-SM-01"
  End Select
  '#### RETURN THE VALUE TO CALLING PROCEDURE:
  findShpc = SHPcT2
End Function
```

Comment: While the + can be used to concatenate strings in VBA, the & would be preferable just to make sure VB is treating it as a string.

Comment: Good point @Jeremy I didn't look closely at the function body to see what if anything they are returning. On closer look, these functions aren't returning any value...

Comment: David... thanks ALOT! great answer and explanation, it worked just as I had in mind.

Comment: You're welcome! Do consider accepting the answer if it's solved the problem :)

Comment: @David there are no errors with data being written from  "N2", I used Range ("N1").Value = "SHP_CAT" to write the Column Header.Thanks again!

Comment: Gotcha. Do the assignment to N1 *outside* of the loop otherwise it repeats unnecessarily